# Swashbuckle SwaggerGen doesn't respect the injected custom Json Serializer

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I'm using [JsonApiSerializer](https://github.com/codecutout/JsonApiSerializer) to comply with Json API Spec as follow:

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var jsonApiFormatter = new JsonOutputFormatter(new JsonApiSerializerSettings(), ArrayPool<char>.Shared);
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonOutputFormatter>();
            options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, jsonApiFormatter);
        });
```

But SwaggerGen ignore it and still use the default Json Serializer (Json.NET)

How can I enforce it to adapt the new serializer.

Comment: Did you find a solution?